# Custom BLoC transformer migration from 7.2.1 to 8.1.0

Tags: flutter, bloc

I just upgraded my bloc package version to `bloc: ^8.1.0` from `bloc: ^7.2.1` so after migration there were some breaking changes deprecated things like `transformEvents` method

In `bloc: ^7.2.1` I have the following code block which helps me to add some debounce for some bloc events;

```dart
  @override
  Stream<Transition<FavouriteEvent, FavouriteState>> transformEvents(
      Stream<FavouriteEvent> events,
      TransitionFunction<FavouriteEvent, FavouriteState> transitionFn) {
    final selectTabEvents = events
        .where((event) => event is SelectTab && event.animatePage == false)
        .debounceTime(Duration(milliseconds: 100));

    final others = events.where((event) =>
        (event is SelectTab && event.animatePage == true) ||
        !(event is SelectTab));
    return super.transformEvents(
      MergeStream([
        selectTabEvents,
        others,
      ]),
      transitionFn,
    );
  }
```

In `bloc: ^8.1.0` I just converted it to the following;

```dart
  EventTransformer<FavouriteEvent> changeTabTransformer(Duration duration) {
    return (Stream<FavouriteEvent> events, mapper) {
      final selectTabEvents = events
          .where((event) => event is SelectTab && event.animatePage == false)
          .debounceTime(Duration(milliseconds: 100));

      final others = events.where((event) =>
          (event is SelectTab && event.animatePage == true) ||
          !(event is SelectTab));

      return MergeStream([
        selectTabEvents,
        others,
      ]);

      // return events.debounceTime(duration).switchMap(mapper);
    };
  }
```

and pass it as a transformer

```dart
on(event,emit){
...
      transformer: changeTabTransformer(
        Duration(
          milliseconds: 100,
        ),
      ),
...
```

but it is not working as expected any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to add `.switchMap(mapper);` to `MergeStream` after adding this it just fixed.

```dart
 EventTransformer<FavouriteEvent> changeTabTransformer(Duration duration) {
    return (Stream<FavouriteEvent> events, mapper) {
      final selectTabEvents = events
          .where((event) => event is SelectTab && event.animatePage == false)
          .debounceTime(Duration(milliseconds: 100));

      final others = events.where((event) =>
          (event is SelectTab && event.animatePage == true) ||
          !(event is SelectTab));

      return MergeStream([
        selectTabEvents,
        others,
      ]).switchMap(mapper);
    };
  }
```